# Laravel Closure Function is not working (with) relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, closures, relation

Hello Developers I hope you are all good.
I have had a problem for 2 or 3 days, and I can't figure out how to solve this. The code is below here. but it always returns

Error: Method name must be a string in file /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 764

```
            $feeds = Feed::where("id",$request->feed_id)
                ->with("media","likes","customer",['comments'=>function($query){
                    foreach ($query as $comment){
                        return $comment->id;
                    }
                }])
                ->first();
```

Comment: what's the purpose of defining closure in `comments`?

Comment: i want each user of that comments, using belongsTo in Comments Model for user

Comment: this is working perfectly i am using this before, 
i just want that i have multiple comments, each comment is related to different user,
i just want that user name and profile pic using reverse relation

Comment: i have a feed
a feed can have many multiple comments
comments can have multiple user (who commented on this feed) ,
i am getting all comments, each comment have a different user , i want that user name with comment, instead of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `with()` to get user name and picture.

```
$feed = Feed::where("id",$request->feed_id)
        ->with([
            "media",
            "likes",
            "customer",
            "comments"=> fn($query) => $query->with('user')
        ])
        ->first();


foreach ($feed->comments as $comment) {
    $user_name = $comment->user->name;
    $user_picture = $comment->user->picture;
}
```